# Automatically start load to BigQuery when file is uploaded to bucket/cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have a script exporting csv-files from another database and uploading them to a bucket on GCP cloud storage. Now I know there's the possibility to schedule loads into BigQuery using BigQuery Data Transfer Service but I am a bit surprised that there doesn't seem to be a solution which triggers automatically when a file-upload is finished.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to handle that event (`google.storage.object.finalize`) by your own means.

For example, that event can trigger a cloud function ([Google Cloud Storage Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage)), which can do various things - from triggering a load job, to implmenting a complex data processing (cleaning, validation, merging, etc.) while the data from the file is being loaded to the BigQuery table.